# Python Pandas replace multiple columns zero to Nan

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-cleaning

List with attributes of persons loaded into pandas dataframe `df2`. For cleanup I want to replace value zero (`0` or `'0'`) by `np.nan`.

```
df2.dtypes

ID                   object
Name                 object
Weight              float64
Height              float64
BootSize             object
SuitSize             object
Type                 object
dtype: object
```

Working code to set value zero to `np.nan`:

```
df2.loc[df2['Weight'] == 0,'Weight'] = np.nan
df2.loc[df2['Height'] == 0,'Height'] = np.nan
df2.loc[df2['BootSize'] == '0','BootSize'] = np.nan
df2.loc[df2['SuitSize'] == '0','SuitSize'] = np.nan
```

Believe this can be done in a similar/shorter way:

```
df2[["Weight","Height","BootSize","SuitSize"]].astype(str).replace('0',np.nan)
```

However the above does not work. The zero's remain in df2. How to tackle this?

Answer (score 119, accepted):

I think you need [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) by `dict`:

```
cols = ["Weight","Height","BootSize","SuitSize","Type"]
df2[cols] = df2[cols].replace({'0':np.nan, 0:np.nan})
```

Comment: I wonder why this solution works, while ```df2[cols].replace({'0':np.nan, 0:np.nan}, inplace=True)``` gives an error `A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame`?

Comment: It's not an error. It's just a warning. Basically, there could be memory issues there.

Comment: @M.Mariscal - Use `.replace({'.':'')`

Comment: Doesnt work, my code is:     cols = ['Total', 'uno', 'dos']
    df[cols] = df[cols].replace({'.':''}) The problem is the to_csv i can see the point but because its thousands, but there is no point... the csv is a mess and i need to sort it ascend but cannot find the correct way

Answer (score 11):

You could use the 'replace' method and pass the values that you want to replace in a list as the first parameter along with the desired one as the second parameter:

```
cols = ["Weight","Height","BootSize","SuitSize","Type"]
df2[cols] = df2[cols].replace(['0', 0], np.nan)
```

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
df2.replace(to_replace={
             'Weight':{0:np.nan}, 
             'Height':{0:np.nan},
             'BootSize':{'0':np.nan},
             'SuitSize':{'0':np.nan},
                 })
```

Comment: this is the cleanest solution IMO. You don't need to pass it in as a kwarg either. Just the dict is fine. For reference -> https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html , the **dict-like `to_replace`** section

Answer (score 4):

```
data['amount']=data['amount'].replace(0, np.nan)
data['duration']=data['duration'].replace(0, np.nan)
```

Answer (score 3):

in column "age", replace zero with blanks

```
df['age'].replace(['0', 0'], '', inplace=True)
```

Replace zero with nan for single column

```
df['age'] = df['age'].replace(0, np.nan)
```

Replace zero with nan for multiple columns

```
cols = ["Glucose", "BloodPressure", "SkinThickness", "Insulin", "BMI"]

df[cols] = df[cols].replace(['0', 0], np.nan)
```

Replace zero with nan for dataframe

```
df.replace(0, np.nan, inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to o replace the zeros in whole dataframe, you can directly replace them without specifying any columns:

```
df = df.replace({0:pd.NA})
```

Comment: This is the fastest way

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative way:

```
cols = ["Weight","Height","BootSize","SuitSize","Type"]
df2[cols] = df2[cols].mask(df2[cols].eq(0) | df2[cols].eq('0'))
```