# Conditionally replacing missing values in Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I am new to Python and am learning few things.

I have a dataset which is coded with strings. A list **columns** contains the names of all the columns in the list.

```
columns = ['median', 'p25th', 'p75th']
```

In this dataset, numbers are stored in the form of strings. Some of the columns do not carry numbers & are represented as **UN** like this:

['110000' '75000' '73000' '70000' '65000' **'UN'** '62000']

['95000' '55000' '50000' '43000' **'UN'** '31500' '48000']

['125000' '90000' '105000' '80000' '75000' '102000' **'UN'** '109000']

I need to replace **UN** with **NaN** using np.nan. 
I used this code below:

```
for column in columns:
    recent_grads.loc[column =='UN', column] = np.nan
```

But I keep getting this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 15, in  recent_grads.loc[column =='UN',
>   column] = np.nan
>
> File "", line 194, in **setitem**
>       self._setitem_with_indexer(indexer, value)    File "", line 332, in _setitem_with_indexer
>       key, _ = convert_missing_indexer(idx)
>
> File "", line 2049, in convert_missing_indexer
>       raise KeyError("cannot use a single bool to index into setitem") KeyError: 'cannot use a single bool to index into setitem'

Can you please tell where I am going wrong? Sorry if this sounds too basic.

Comment: Use recent_grads[column] instead of column

Comment: Is it a list or a dataframe?

Comment: Its a list not a dataframe.
No that does not work. The same error arises again.

Comment: @Keerthana Share the code to create the dataframe. That way, we'll be able to reproduce the problem at our ends too.

Comment: this might work, but the suggested answer is much better: `recent_grads.loc[recent_grads[column] == 'UN', column] = np.nan`

Comment: @IanS Yes! that's what I was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: Also thanks to @Vishnudev Sorry I misplaced the square brackets the first time you pointed out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to use Pandas DataFrame [`replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html), like shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45416749/4057186)

Data

```
d = [['median', 'p25th', 'p75th'],
     ['110000','75000','73000','70000','65000','UN','62000'],
     ['95000','55000','50000','43000','UN','31500','48000'],
     ['125000','90000','80000','75000','102000','UN','109000']
    ]
recent_grads = pd.DataFrame(zip(*d[1:]), columns=d[0])
print(recent_grads)

   median  p25th   p75th
0  110000  95000  125000
1   75000  55000   90000
2   73000  50000   80000
3   70000  43000   75000
4   65000     UN  102000
5      UN  31500      UN
6   62000  48000  109000
```

Code

```
import numpy as np
columns = ['median', 'p25th', 'p75th']
recent_grads[columns] = recent_grads[columns].replace('UN', np.nan)
print(recent_grads)

   median  p25th   p75th
0  110000  95000  125000
1   75000  55000   90000
2   73000  50000   80000
3   70000  43000   75000
4   65000    NaN  102000
5     NaN  31500     NaN
6   62000  48000  109000
```

Comment: This works! But the website am working with wants me to use for loop

    for column in ____:
      recent_grads[columns]=recent_grads[column=____,column]

where we have to replace some code in these blank spaces.

Comment: In that case the [answer posted by @IanS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53157088/conditionally-replacing-missing-values-in-pandas/53157357?noredirect=1#comment93206107_53157088) is correct. This was also suggested by @ Vishnudev [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53157088/conditionally-replacing-missing-values-in-pandas/53157357?noredirect=1#comment93204750_53157088).

Comment: Yes! now got it! I accidentally misplaced the square brackets. Sorry & Thank you for helping me out.