# How to use replace method on multiple columns col0,col1,col2 with multiple conditons

Tags: python, pandas

How to use replace method on multiple columns col0,col1,col2

```
new_df['col0'].str.replace(']]', ']')
```

Comment: can you post input and expected output?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Pandas replace multiple columns zero to Nan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45416684/python-pandas-replace-multiple-columns-zero-to-nan)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html):

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame({'col0':[']]','aa]]'],
                       'col1':[']]','[s]'],
                       'col2':['[[]]]]',']'],
                       'col3':[']]', '[[]]]']})
print (new_df)
   col0 col1    col2   col3
0    ]]   ]]  [[]]]]     ]]
1  aa]]  [s]       ]  [[]]]

cols = ['col0','col1','col2']
new_df[cols] = new_df[cols].replace(']]', ']')
print (new_df)
   col0 col1    col2   col3
0     ]    ]  [[]]]]     ]]
1  aa]]  [s]       ]  [[]]]
```

If want replace substrings add `regex=True` with escaping by `\` because `[` is special `regex` character:

```
cols = ['col0','col1','col2']
new_df[cols] = new_df[cols].replace('\]\]', ']', regex=True)
print (new_df)
  col0 col1  col2   col3
0    ]    ]  [[]]     ]]
1  aa]  [s]     ]  [[]]]
```

EDIT: If possible, convert values to lists:

```
import ast

test=pd.DataFrame({'gender':['M']*4,'B':[[['Office/Work'],['31-35'], ['Salaried']],[['Movies,Restaurants'],['21-25'], ['Salaried']],[[ 'College/Park'],['21-25'],['Student']],[['College'], ['21-25'], ['Student']]]})
test = test.astype(str)
print (test)
  gender                                                  B
0      M         [['Office/Work'], ['31-35'], ['Salaried']]
1      M  [['Movies,Restaurants'], ['21-25'], ['Salaried']]
2      M         [['College/Park'], ['21-25'], ['Student']]
3      M              [['College'], ['21-25'], ['Student']]

df = pd.DataFrame([[y[0] for y in ast.literal_eval(x)] for x in test['B']],
                   columns=['a','b','c'])
print (df)
                    a      b         c
0         Office/Work  31-35  Salaried
1  Movies,Restaurants  21-25  Salaried
2        College/Park  21-25   Student
3             College  21-25   Student
```

Solution with `replace`:

```
df = test['B'].replace(['\[\[','\]\]', '\], \['], ['', '', ';'], regex=True).str.split(';', expand=True)
print (df)
                      0        1           2
0         'Office/Work'  '31-35'  'Salaried'
1  'Movies,Restaurants'  '21-25'  'Salaried'
2        'College/Park'  '21-25'   'Student'
3             'College'  '21-25'   'Student'
```

Comment: if i want to replace `,[` what need to be done also please how to remove `['`

Comment: @ain - Can you create some sample data, [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ?

Comment: test=pd.DataFrame({'gender':['M'],'B':[[['Office/Work'],['31-35'], ['Salaried']]}) > out > 'Office/Work', '31-35', 'Salaried'