# Unable to read TweetId in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, tweepy

I have a list of tweet id(with none values) in an excel file

```
ID
1258125182063050753
1233371388620263429
1237667024618258432
1225204912755179521
nan
nan
```

When I try to load the excel file in Pandas datagram, I convert the string column in interfere using

```
df['ID']=df['ID'].apply(np.int64)
```

I am getting the values as

```
 1258125182063050752
 1233371388620263424
 1237667024618258432
 1225204912755179520
 0
 0
```

The conversion of string to integer changes the numeric values. How can I rectify the issue?

Comment: Do you mean changing the zeros (0) back to NaNs?   Check this: [Python Pandas replace multiple columns zero to Nan] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45416684/python-pandas-replace-multiple-columns-zero-to-nan)

Comment: @naccode no, my concern is  1258125182063050753 becomes  1258125182063050752 after the conversion

Comment: why do you convert to integer ? you don't have to make calculations on these numbers so keep them as strings.

Comment: BTW: did you check values in Pandas before converting? Maybe you already have wrong data. Did you load directly from Excel or from CSV? Did you check CSV in text editor to see if you have correct values in file ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is an issue of number precision in Excel file, because when checking in pure python I see conversion doesn't change numbers:

```
df['ID2'] = df['ID'].apply(np.int64)
df['ID2'] == df['ID']

0    True
1    True
2    True
3    True
dtype: bool
```

Comment: maybe, but how to deal with the problem of excel/csv?

Comment: To reproduce problem the Excel file is needed and code showing the way You are importing data into dataframe. Also consoder that what You ca see in excel depends on formating options aplied to cells in worksheet.